# Accessibility Voice Control to Read a Navigate a Webpage

Tags: samsung, voice-command, accessibility

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S10e and I would like to use my accessibility features to voice control my phone while driving. I would like to be able to navigate to a website and have the content read to me and use voice commands to give commands within the website like, "skip link" "Fill-out form" and "tap link." Does anyone know if this is possible with Android's built-in accessibility and if so how so I do it?

I am also willing to use an App if there are any out there that will allow me to voice control navigation and read content to me. Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Android's built-in Accessibility really focuses on reading/speaking items on the screen and using gestures to move around.

For voice control, one possibility is [Google's Voice Access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess) app in the Play Store, and the intro tutorial does give a good example of the app's features, but there seems to be some problems with the form-filling (speech to text into a field) when I tried it just now. I also noticed that it uses small numbers for focus change which may not be desirable while driving.

Using an Accessibility app is pretty invasive from a permissions point of view so provided that you trust Google and can work around the current defects it is probably worth trying out.